# Re publishing android app using updated JDK Ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2

Just a question. I recently published a first version of an app to the the android store and the private key that was generated happened with the JAVA_HOME set to jdk1.7.0_79. However, after update Android Studio yesterday I also needed to update the jdk and now JAVA_HOME is set to jdk1.8.9_101.

What I want to know is if I publish and updated version of the current app..do I need to re-create the key using jdk1.8.0_101?

I am a bit worried to break the existing app as it is already used by the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the jdk from 1.7 to 1.8 and I published a new version of my app with the old key and everything was fine. you shouldn't use another key or you won’t be able to submit updates to your app!